# Is there a way to get true client's ip address in dns servers?

Tags: dns

As much as I'm aware of, when a Dns server gets a request for a name translation, there is a very high chance that it comes from another Dns server delegating (intercepting) a clients request. So the src Ip would not be the address of the real client. Is there a Dns response, something like,

> HERE IS THE CNAME FOR THAT DOMAIN, BUT LET THAT CLIENT ASK DIRECTLY THE A RECORD OF THAT CNAME FROM ME

Or any other solutions for DNS, to get the IP of requesting client (NOT OTHER Recursion DNS resolver) for a public Dns like that will be highly appreciated

Thank YOU

Answer (score 2):

There is a DNS extension called ([ECS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDNS_Client_Subnet)) may satisfy your need.
It contains *client IP subnet* in DNS query for better resolution.

Also, set DNS query **Recursion Desired** bit to 0 on client side can do iterative DNS query.
But this is up to the client to set the flag, and it's needed to set TTL to 0 in DNS response to prevent other DNS server from returning cached record.

Neither approach can make client **MUST**send it's true IP to DNS server, maybe there is a better way depends on the actual problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing remotely like that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Although I myself think there is no solution for that in DNS protocol, pleas see my updated question

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is still no. Think for example of the case where two clients ask the recursor at the same time. The recursor will still only send one query to your server. It will also cache the answer for some period of time, and any clients who ask during that time your server will never even know about.

Comment: yes of course. Actually I was hopelessly looking for some solution, some extra fields in protocol that not only prevent recursors from caching but but also make rest of the job easier for me. anyway think it is done. Thank you, I +1 you and let this question be open for sometimes.